# What is a "Revenue Credit" on a 401k account statement?

Tags: united-states, 401k

My 401k statement has a new entry labeled "Revenue Credit".   This amount is a small amount of significantly less than 1% and less than the expense ratio for any of the funds in the account.  There is an entry for "Revenue Credit" for each fund held by the account.

What is this "Revenue Credit"? Why is it a credit?

This is an active 401k account held with Fidelity in which I am currently contributing.

Comment: What does the plan administrator or the HR department have to say about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick search via google shows that some 401K programs are refunding money to the employees if the cost of running the program were lower than originally estimated.

Here is one such explanation:

> As was communicated in the plan transition guide in September 2012,
> the University of Washington has negotiated a fee credit from
> Fidelity. Beginning in January 2013, a credit was allocated to
> participants who invest in mutual funds for which Fidelity receives
> revenue to offset administrative costs. (See Appendix).
>
> Revenue
> credits are commonly negotiated for and given to plan sponsors in
> order to help them offset plan expenses. Rather than keep this credit,
> however, the UW has chosen to reallocate it back to the participants
> who actually hold the funds.
>
> Any credit allocated to your account will
> appear on your quarterly benefits statement and will be invested in
> the fund to which the credit relates, and allocated proportionally to
> the sources associated with such fund for each Participant.